# EADDRINUSE when using subdomains

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel

Assume you have 2 ASP.NET core projects; an API and a website.
I want to approach these locally (and simultaneously, since the website uses the api) using the following url's: `devapi.website.com` and `dev.website.com`.

Currently, I can only get this to work when I specify a different port number for both projects in the `Program.cs` file (and by using said port numbers in my browser):

**API**

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
     .UseUrls("http://devapi.website.com:81")
     .UseKestrel()
     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .UseIISIntegration()
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .Build();
```

**Website**

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
     .UseUrls("http://dev.website.com:82")
     .UseKestrel()
     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .UseIISIntegration()
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .Build();
```

And in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 devapi.website.com
127.0.0.1 dev.website.com
```

If I specify the same port number (or, as a matter of fact, none at all - I want to use port 80) in `Program.cs`, one project will run and the other will throw

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4091 EADDRINUSE address already in use

on startup.

How can I run these 2 projects simultaneously without specifying different port numbers?

Comment: Nate is right, this doesn't work. With Kestrel you are expected to use more or less randomized port numbers, because Kestrel is not meant to be directly facing to the internet. Kestrel must always be used behind a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy may use different host names on same port and redirect the traffic internaly (i.e. devapi.example.com to localhost:5000 and dev.example.com to localhost:5001).

Comment: You can however use WebListener, web listener allows you to share ports (on same or different hosts), but web listener only works on Windows. The reverse proxy is the right scenario for .net core/portable scenarios, unless you need Ntlm/windows authentication, this only works on web listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible, at least not without a workaround. Here's why:

Binding Kestrel to a DNS name like `dev.website.com` doesn't make any difference to how Kestrel is listening to requests. It still has to tie up a port (80 by default). If you try to have two instances of Kestrel bind to 80, whichever one is launched first actually gets the port, and the other will error.

Adding the names to your hosts file doesn't matter; all that does is make both `devapi.website.com` and `dev.website.com` resolve to `127.0.0.1`. You only have one port 80 to bind to. The only way to run two HTTP servers on your machine is to bind them to separate ports.

You could achieve the same functionality a slightly different way:

1. Bind your instances of Kestrel to separate ports - `80/81`, or `50080/50080`, etc.
2. Use a tunneling tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) to create separate tunnels that terminate at those ports.

For example, with localtunnel,

```
lt --port 50080
lt --port 50081
```

You'll get two URLs like https://gqgh.localtunnel.me and https://fydh.localtunnel.me, which will point to your separate Kestrel servers. They aren't on your domain (which may be a non-starter, depending on your situation), but at least they're separate public URLs.

Comment: Thanks Nate, that makes sense. I'll give localtunnel a try - or go with a different strategy.

Comment: @Nate what's the difference with IIS where you can create two sites with a different hostname and the same port?